# "BS_" rows in postmeta table

Tags: database, post-meta, mysql, wpdb

I am pruning my WordPress site's MySQL database and noticed that there are thousands of rows in the `postmeta` table with the prefix "BS_".

```
BS_author_type
BS_guest_author_name
BS_guest_author_url
BS_guest_author_description
BS_guest_author_image_id
```

Are these generated by WordPress or by a plugin that I might have added and removed before? I tried googling the meta-keys as well as the prefix `BS_` and the only result I got is a Romanian webpage with random code and a few images on it.

Comment: They're from https://wordpress.org/plugins/guest-author/. The keys obviously suggested they were from a guest author plugin, so I searched Google for guest author plugins, opened the first result, browsed the code, and found that it uses those keys.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks man. Can u u please add that as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're from wordpress.org/plugins/guest-author. The keys suggested they were from a guest author plugin, so I searched Google for guest author plugins, opened the first result, browsed the code, and found that it uses those keys.